# A Question about Annihilation and Creation Operators in the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, poisson-brackets

I'm new to quantum mechanics and I just have a doubt.

If $\hat a$ is the annihilation operator of quantum harmonic oscillator and $ \hat a^{\dagger}$ is the creation operator, what is the value of $\langle 0|\hat{a} \, \hat{a}^{\dagger}|0 \rangle$?

I think it should be $0$, since the annihilation operator acts on the left bra. But I just realized if I work on the right first bra-ket, I get: $\langle 1|1 \rangle=1$.

I'm just confused at the moment. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The annihilation operator acts as a *creation* operator when it acts to the left on the bra.

Comment: I understand finally. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another way to look at it: since $\langle 0|\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}|0\rangle=0$, $\langle0|\hat{a}\hat{a}^\dagger|0\rangle=\langle 0|[\hat{a},\,\hat{a}^\dagger]|0\rangle=\langle 0|1|0\rangle=1$.

Answer (score 3):

These operators has the following properties: $a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$ and $a^\dagger|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle$, so:
$$\langle0|a a^\dagger |0\rangle=\langle0|a\sqrt{0+1}|1\rangle=\langle 0|\sqrt{1}|0\rangle=1$$
The annihilation operator acts on left bra as following: $$\langle0|a=(a^\dagger|0\rangle)^\dagger=(|1\rangle)^\dagger=\langle1| $$

Answer (score 2):

The key point to remember is that $$\left(A|\psi\rangle\right)^\dagger=\left(\langle\psi|A^\dagger\right),$$ where I am using the $^\dagger$ for Hermitian conjugation. Equivalently,
$$\left(A^\dagger|\psi\rangle\right)^\dagger=\left(\langle\psi|A\right).$$ We can use this in your expression to simplify
$$\langle 0|a=(a^+|0\rangle)^\dagger$$ (your notation's $^+$ is the same as my $^\dagger) and the contradiction is resolved.

Comment: thanks a lot. its' clear now.